# Display an Android live wallpaper in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

Is there any way to display an Android live wallpaper in a fragment? I have a live wallpaper, and currently if the user wants to change some settings, they need to click settings, make a change, hit the back button, and see if the change is what they want. For certain wallpapers, the user doesn't exactly know what numbers they want, and usually they figure out the settings through experimentation, so the current method of going back and forth between the settings and the preview is a pain.

Right now a lot of the settings are in the form of a slider fragment that I wrote. I was wondering if it is possible to include a preview of the wallpaper in the fragment that will change live with the slider?

Comment: If you can extract the core of your live wallpaper to a View, then you can stick it in a Fragment for sure.

Comment: @dmon Right, but I have a lot of code in the Engine, so I was hoping for an easy way to just use the Engine.

Comment: @dmon I don't think your entire comment posted successfully. At least, I only see half of it.